# Is there a way to find the instance of a scratch org in Trust Status?

Tags: scratch-org

I want to find if there is any announcement (incident and/or maintenance) on [Trust Status site](https://status.salesforce.com/) for a given scratch org, how can I do that?

The only way I found so far was to get the instance URL through `sfdx force:org:display` but that only work if I created the scratch org.

Comment: If you already have one created and you can access the UI, you can check your cookies to see what node/pod you are running on (I.e. naXX, apXX, etc.) and then look at the status of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any Salesforce org, including scratch orgs, you can find the instance via Setup->Company Information, or by querying the [`InstanceName` field on `Organization`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm).

Scratch orgs will be on sandbox instances, which you can look up on Trust.