# Dreadful CI Performance

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

I have built a continuous integration process using CircleCI for my large managed package. There are about 7,000 deployed components.  The performance I am seeing is absolutely dreadful.  I am using an Org Shape (Partner Developer Edition) for my scratch org creation.

The deployment of the code takes about 20 minutes versus 5 minutes if done from my PC to a vanilla DE instance.  The apex tests take 50 minutes(!!!) versus about 5 minutes in a vanilla DE instance.

I am hoping I am doing something suboptimal in my config.yml.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

My config.yml:

```
version: 2.1
general:
jobs:
  build:
    machine:
      image: ubuntu-2004:current
    resource_class: large
    working_directory: ~/ci_app
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install CLI
          command: |
            node --version
            npm install sfdx-cli --global
            sfdx --version
      - run:
          name: Create Hub Key
          command: |
            echo 'make hub key'
            openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in .circleci/server.key.enc -out .circleci/server.key -base64 -K $DECRYPTION_KEY -iv $DECRYPTION_IV
      - run:
          name: Set Up Org
          no_output_timeout: 60m
          command: |
            ls -al
            pwd
            echo 'Grant/Create/Push'
            #
            sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $HUB_CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile .circleci/server.key --username $HUB_SFDC_USER --setdefaultdevhubusername -a hub            
            sfdx force:org:create -s -f .circleci/project-scratch-def.json -a circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM -d 1 -w 30
            #
            # sfdx force:data:tree:import -f .circleci/currency.json
            #
            sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "select Username, Name, LanguageLocaleKey, Country, CountryCode, IsActive, LocaleSidKey, TimeZoneSidKey from User"            
            sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "select Country, CountryCode, LanguageLocaleKey, OrganizationType, TimeZoneSidKey from Organization"
            sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "select DeveloperName, IsActive from DuplicateRule"
            #
            sfdx force:source:push -u circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM -w 30
            sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d .circleci -w 10
      - run:
          name: Run Apex Tests
          no_output_timeout: 60m
          command: |
            mkdir -p ~/junit
            sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -d ~/junit -r human
      - store_test_results:
          path: ~/junit
      - run:
          name: Delete Scratch Org
          command: |
            sfdx force:org:delete -u circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM -p
          when: always
```

The dreadful performance:

[image]

Comment: A few things to check: (1) is Parallel Apex Testing turned off in your scratch org definition or shape? (2) If you create a Shape-based scratch org locally, can you reproduce a significant delay that accounts for much or all of the setup time? I see your deploy wait is set to 10 minutes, so it can't account for more than ~1/3rd of the time consumed. (3) If you remove the `-c` coverage flag, what kind of impact on test time do you see?

Comment: There is also currently a problem with slow execution of Apex tests generally. We have a support case open for this. Our tests have gone from ~8min to ~40min since 20th April or there abouts.

Comment: Thanks, guys.  Yes the scratch org parallel testing is ON.  David, I will try your local test and also remove the -c flag and let you know.

Comment: Does anyone have any experience using perhaps a windows execution environment instead of ubuntu on CircleCI?  I wonder if it would be faster....

Comment: Also I should have made this clear:  The "sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d .circleci -w 10" is to upload 5 duplicate rules in inactive state as the scratch org inactive duplicate rules are not copied correctly when used as a shape.  So no big time contributor for this statement.  All the "real" code goes up here:  sfdx force:source:push -u circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM -w 30

Comment: I removed the -c from the apex test CLI command and that shaved about 5 minutes.

Comment: I also tried explicitly setting the shape settings for testing:  {
    "orgName": "Scratch2-SC-US-TMS",
    "sourceOrg": "00D8b0000xxxxxx",
    "features": ["PlatformCache"],
    "settings": {
        "apexSettings": {
            "enableAggregateCodeCoverageOnly": true,
            "enableDisableParallelApexTesting": false,
            "enableGaplessTestAutoNum": true
        }
    }    
}   but that did not help at all.

Comment: Sorry, if I have missed this somewhere in your comments, but did you experience the same slowness, when doing the configured steps manually (as suggested by David Reed point 2) instead of using the yml? (Scratch org instead of DE etc.)

Comment: Felix and Dave -- I tried the exact same commands locally from Visual Studio Code on my Windows PC using the same scratch org shape.  THE SAME TERRIBLE PERFORMANCE.  I also noticed that apex unit tests seem to run only with two threads even though I have NOT disabled parallel testing.

Comment: Since the lousy performance is the same whether via CircleCI or my PC, I wonder if we can lay all of this on the scratch orgs being criminally underpowered?

Comment: Have you reviewed that the settings in the config file are being applied in the scratch org? I had a similar issue that some settings were completely ignored when creating a new scratch org. I think that manually deploying them fixed this

Comment: Thanks for that idea.  When I reproduced the steps from VS Code I was able to log in and inspect the scratch org.  It does appear that the settings are transferred from the shape org.  BUT the scratch org performance is terrible as I could log in and observe the terrible deploy and test performance first hand.

Comment: @DaveC check on salesforce trust if there are known performance issue with the scratch org instance https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285675/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-instance-of-a-scratch-org-in-trust-status

Comment: Thanks, Shamina.